# How to set image for tabbar item in ios 6 and ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to set image for tabbar item in ios 6 and ios 7. My tabbar only run in ios 7 because imageWithRenderingMode method is not run in ios 6. How to set tab bar item run in  ios 6 and 7. Thank in advance. This is my code.

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
 UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];

 tabBarItem1.title = @"Phim mới";
 tabBarItem2.title = @"Xem phim";
 tabBarItem3.title = @"GS Xoay";
 tabBarItem4.title = @"Về chúng tôi";

 [tabBarItem1 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic1.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

 [tabBarItem2 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic2.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

 [tabBarItem3 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic3.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

 [tabBarItem4 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic4.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
 return YES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check to see if the method exists at runtime:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic1.jpg"];
if ([image1 respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {
    [tabBarItem1 setImage:[image1 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [tabBarItem2 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic2.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [tabBarItem3 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic3.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [tabBarItem4 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic4.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
} else {
    [tabBarItem1 setImage:image1];
    [tabBarItem2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic2.jpg"]];
    [tabBarItem3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic3.jpg"]];
    [tabBarItem4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic4.jpg"]];
}
```

I suggest you read the "[SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html)" in the documentation.